# Executar código JavaScript ao clicar em link dentro de DIV

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

Tenho esse código javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var domain = '<?=$x['host']?>';
    var auto_surf = <?=($site['surf_type'] == 1 ? 0 : 1)?>;
    var sid = '<?=$sit['id']?>';
    var hash = '<?=MD5(rand(1000,9999))?>';
    var barsize = 1;
    var maxbarsize = 250;
    var numbercounter = <?=$surf_time?>;
    var numbercounter_n = <?=$surf_time?>;
    var adtimer = null;
    var focusFlag = 1;
    var fc_override = <?=($site['surf_fc_req'] == 1 ? 0 : 1)?>;
    var fc_skip = <?=($site['surf_fb_skip'] == 1 ? 1 : 0)?>;
    var buster_listener = 1;
    var buster = 0;
    var buster_red = '?skip=<?=$sit['id']?>&bd';
    var surf_file = 'surf.php';
    var can_leave = <?=($sit['id'] == 0 ? 'true' : 'false')?>;
    var report_msg1 = '<?=mysql_escape_string($lang['b_277'])?>';
    var report_msg2 = '<?=mysql_escape_string($lang['b_236'])?>';
    var report_msg3 = '<?=mysql_escape_string($lang['b_237'])?>';
    window.onbeforeunload = <?=($site['surf_fb_skip'] == 1 ? 'bust' : 'function () {if (can_leave == false) {var a = "";var b = b || window.event;if (b) {b.returnValue = a;}return a;}}')?>;
</script>
```

Porém quero executar esse código ao clicar em um link dentro dessa DIV:

```
<div class="fb-post" onclick="test()" data-href="<?=($sit['url'] == '' ? ($site['surf_type'] != 1 ? 'system/modules/surf/nocoins.html' : 'system/modules/surf/nopage.html') : hideref($sit['url'], ($site['hideref'] == 1 ? 1 : ($site['hideref'] == 2 ? 2 : 0)), (empty($site['revshare_api']) ? 0 : $site['revshare_api'])))?>" data-width="750" data-show-text="false"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que registrar um evento para ficar monitorando a ação de **click** na sua **div**. Note que aqui está sendo monitorado todos os elementos que tenham o **className** igual a **fb-post**, onde **className** corresponde ao atributo **class** da sua tag **div**.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelector('.fb-post').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // coloque o seu código aqui dentro
  })
});
```

Eu recomendo fortemente que não misture código **PHP** com **JavaScript**. Também dê uma pesquisada no termo **JavaScript Não-Obstrutivo** e **HTML Semântico**.

Comment: sou matuto kkkkk
como fica o código?

Comment: no caso ficaria assim:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelector('.fb-post').addEventListener('click', function() {
  <script type="text/javascript">
  CODIGO JAVASCRIPT
</script>

  })
});

Comment: alguem ?pra me ajudar e muto importatne

Comment: Aquilo que eu lhe passei é código JavaScript. Então basta colocar o trecho de código JS que você quiser ali dentro.

Comment: no caso ficaria assim?

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { document.querySelector('.fb-post').addEventListener('click', function() { <script type="text/javascript"> CODIGO JAVASCRIPT </script> }) });

Comment: Alguem pra ver se ta certo?